# Div keeps adding unnecessary margin

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar div in my website. Sometimes it stays at the top and sometimes it adds unnecessary margin-top.  I'm not sure what's wrong. I checked my website, it's not collapsing with any margin for any of my div. I am very confused. I tried to use position but that did not work. Can anyone help? Here's my code snippet :

```css
        .container-navbar{
           background-color: #ffffff;
           height: 60px;
           display: flex;
           justify-content: space-between;
           box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
           transition:5s;
        }
        .button-collapse-sidebar{
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }
        .button-collapse-sidebar button{
            height: 40px;
            width: 60px;
            font-size: 20px;
            border:none;
            background-color: blue;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        .button-collapse-sidebar button:hover{
            transition: 1.5s;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            z-index: 2;
        }
        .user{
            display: flex;
        }
        .user-name{
            padding: 18px;
        }
        .user-name i{
            padding-left: 5px;
        }
        .user-name i,a{
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .user-picture{
            margin-top:5px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            width: 60px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            border-radius: 50%;
            height: 50px;
        }

        .user-picture img{
            width: 100%;
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            bottom: 0;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-navbar">
        <div class="button-collapse-sidebar">
            <button class="button-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="user">
            <div class="user-name">
                <a href="">Admin name<i class="fas fa-circle"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="user-picture">
                <img src="" alt="user-picture">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

so i update the code and add the body{ margin:0; } here i have 2 different file html but with same html tag and css but for some reason my main one not working but my test html it work and not adding the unnecessary margin-top.

[image: this one not working]

[image: this one work]

Comment: Add the `*` selector with `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` at the top of your CSS

Comment: normalizing css is best. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62846267/10002142

Comment: i update my question and add the margin:0;  in my body css, can you review it please. there are 2 file that i am testing one that is my main and other is my testing both of them have same css and html tag my test html file work it not adding the margin top but my main html still adding the unnecessary margin-top. i don't know maybe this is a browser bug or there's some thing wrong with my code.

Comment: `*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}`  

Use this in the first line of styling

Answer (score 2):

When a browser renders an HTML page, it applies basic styles before you’ve even written a single style.

For Example, the `<h1>` to `<h6>` HTML tags in all browsers differ from the normal text:
in general, their font sizes are larger, their font-weight is bold(`font-weight: bold`), and they have margins on the top & the bottom.

While all browsers apply their basic styles, each browser has its specific styles different from other browsers, and that, of course, causes an inconsistency problem. That’s the problem that you are talking about in this question.
The attempt to solve the browser inconsistency problem has produced two approaches: **[the Normalize CSS](https://medium.com/@elad/normalize-css-or-css-reset-9d75175c5d1e)** approach and the **[CSS Reset approach](https://medium.com/@elad/normalize-css-or-css-reset-9d75175c5d1e)**.

Comment: i update my question and add the margin:0;  in my body css, can you review it please. there are 2 file that i am testing one that is my main and other is my testing both of them have same css and html tag my test html file work it not adding the margin top but my main html still adding the unnecessary margin-top. i don't know maybe this is a browser bug or there's some thing wrong with my code.

Comment: Did you used Normalize css??

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about this [margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kByDG.png), you can simply add

```
   body{
       margin : 0px;
   }
```

in your CSS. That should solve your issue. If you only want to remove margin on the top, use `margin-top` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As for now, you can get used to adding this at the top of your css-file:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This will remove all paddings and margins and box-sizing will simply make it easier for you. [Mozilla box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

Answer (score 0):

that's a simple reset you can do for your website:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```